# problem with converting time zone from UTC to CST6CDT

Tags: time

I have a dataset that I want to have read as tz= CST6CDT. I read the file in and then convert t (timestamp) to POSIXct using the following code.

pindf<-read_csv(here("data/cleaned_pintail/nopi_adj.csv"))
pindf$t<- as.POSIXct(pindf$t, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="CST6CDT")

When I check to see if the time zone is correct, it provides the tz as UTC.

I tried re-installing the lubridate package as was suggested in a previous question but it did not fix my issue. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Nowhere did you specify what you are using, this might make it hard for a potential answer to find its way to your questions.

At least adding a tag, or being specific in the question title will make it easier to identify that they have a possible answer, or know the technology related to it.

For example, using the title: Problem converting time zone from UTC to CST6CDT using lubridate

Adding a lubridate tag could also help.